# Is catching DocumentException a good idea?

Tags: java

I have a utility method which reads an xml file and converts to string as below:

```
public static String readFile(String xmlFileName) throws IOException, DocumentException{
        String xmlMsg = null;
        Resource resource = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            resource = new ClassPathResource(xmlFileName);
            inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            Document doc = reader.read( inputStream );
            xmlMsg = doc.asXML();
        }finally{
            if(inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return xmlMsg;
    }
```

Is it a bad idea if I catch the DocumentException in the above code and rethrow it as below:

```
public static String readFile(String xmlFileName) throws IOException, DocumentException{
        String xmlMsg = null;
        Resource resource = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            resource = new ClassPathResource(xmlFileName);
            inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            Document doc = reader.read( inputStream );
            xmlMsg = doc.asXML();
        }catch (DocumentException e){
           throw new DocumentException("some message");
        }finally{
            if(inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return xmlMsg;
    }
```

So, is it a bad idea to leave the responsibility of handling the DocumentException to the caller?

Comment: What benefit are you trying to get by catching an exception only to immediately throw a new exception of the same type?  Both of these code snippets "leave the responsibility of handling the `DocumentException` to the caller", but the second suppresses the message and stack trace of the original error, making it harder to debug.

Comment: If a `DocumentException` does get thrown, what do you expect the caller to do with it? If it's something that you *expect* to happen every now and again then catch it where it makes sense to provide the contingency code. If it should never happen then I'd just wrap it in a `RuntimeException` and let the fault barrier handle it.

Comment: I agree with you.Will it be OK if I throw a custom Exception instead of re throwing DocumentException?

Comment: @JonK, That sounds good to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, leaving the caller to handle the `Exception` is fine - [throw early catch late](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late).

What I have a problem with is this:

```
}catch (DocumentException e){
    throw new DocumentException("some message");
```

Why would you `catch (DocumentException e)` and then throw a new instance that **strips out all useful information**? You can simply *not catch* it in the first place and let it percolate up to someone who can handle it.

Also, use Java 7 try-with-resources rather than `finally`. So, you code should be:

```
public static String readFile(String xmlFileName) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    try (final InputStream is = new ClassPathResource(xmlFileName).getInputStream()) {
        final SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        final Document doc = reader.read(inputStream);
        return doc.asXML();
    }
}
```

I have removed the variables that are declared as `null` then reassigned, I **hate** this practice and so do many other Java developers - get out of this habit. Declare things *when you need them* and *assign them immediately*. In a garbage collected language the principal of minimum scope is very important.

I have also changed it to `return` directly rather than storing the value for some reason.

Comment: +1.  On the topic of null variables, Guava's [Using and avoiding null](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) is always an excellent read.

Comment: @dimo414 and with Java 8 there is no longer the need to use `null` _anywhere_. Yey!

Comment: @Boris the Spider +1 for neat explanation.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    catch (DocumentException e){ // here you are catching exception
       throw new DocumentException("some message");// now you are changing
       // exception message 
    }
```

That is a bad practice you have to throw originally thrown exception to upper level then you can handle the `Exception` there.

This way is better

```
   catch (DocumentException e){
       throw new DocumentException("some message",e);
   }
```

Comment: If re-throwing the _same class_ the best practice is not to catch it in the first place... I you want to change the message, it's also advantageous to wrap the exception in a custom class.